# Triggering event handler attached to it's own object, but inside a chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, user-interface, chaining

Right now I have:

```
$("#myElement").bind("buildTimeline", function (event, newViewObj) {
    curDomObj = $(this).children(".timeline"); //this refers to #myElement

    curDomObj.draggable({
        axis:"x",
        drag:curDomObj.trigger("drag")
    });
});
```

I'd much rather just have one chain, but is there a way to refer to the current element at your position in the chain?:

```
$(this).children(".timeline").draggable({
    axis:"x",
    drag:$(this).trigger("drag") //this still refers to #myElement, but I want
                                 //it to refer to #myElement .timeline
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
$("#myElement").bind("buildTimeline", function (event, newViewObj) {
    $(this).children(".timeline").draggable({
        axis:"x",
        drag:$(this).children(".timeline").trigger("drag")
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid touching the dom (using $(this).children(".timeline") again) an extra time like this (not that I know if it even really does)

Comment: Well ultimately I think you have the best solution already, you'll probably have to get used to breaking the chain that way at times if you want to keep optimal performance.